# How can I get the list of changes that user W made between date X and date Y which affected directory Z?

Tags: perforce, p4v, revision-history, changelist

I think the command is [`p4 changes`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_changes.html), but I can't figure out the syntax for what I want.

I tried with

```bash
p4 changes -u myusername @2021/09/08,2022/04/04 /path/to/directory
```

where the date interval and the user name seem to be honored, but the path is not, so I think I've misunderstood what the doc means by *`//depot/project/...`* in this example:

> `p4 changes -m 5 //depot/project/...` Show the last five submitted, pending, or shelved changelists that include any file under the `project` directory.

I tried taking the path from the address bar in Perforce Helix P4V when I select the file in the depot.

Answer (score 3):

The revision specifier modifies the file path and they go together as a single argument:

```
p4 changes -u myusername /path/to/directory/...@2021/09/08,2022/04/04
```

See `p4 help changes` and `p4 help revisions`.

A lot of commands like `p4 changes` take a `file[revRange]` argument; in the above example `/path/to/directory/...` is `file` and `@2021/09/08,2022/04/04` is `revRange`.

If you specify a `revRange` on its own then `file` is implicitly `//...`, which is why the first version of the command you tried returned results across the entire depot.  The `/path/to/directory` was interpreted as a separate argument; if you left off the trailing `...` wildcard it wouldn't match any files, so that part of the result was just empty.